# What's a Texel-Space Height Derivative and how do I calculate it?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, directx, derivative

The specific context is here:

http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2012/01/11/derivative-maps/

It's an article about bump mapping. Specifically, the author mentions "texel-space height derivatives". I'm not sure what this means.

*Texel-Space* I believe refers to the width and height of the texture/image. The texture/image itself isn't colour values, it's height values. So, I imagine the texel-space height derivative would be the (x,y) slope on each pixel in relation to the neighbouring pixels in the x and y directions?

How would I even calculate this? I don't understand what the size of the texture has to do with the local slope, especially considering if the pixel is at the lowest of it's neighbours in the x and y directions, what would it's slope be?

Comment: Yes, it's just the delta between neighbouring height values. E.g. `height(x+1,y)-height(x-1, y)` for the `x` derivative (I assume). It's pretty similar to a normal map but `z` can be computed implicitly so you don't need to store it. I guess there are also some precision factors involved which are discussed in the article.

Comment: Oooh... *texel* space, not *texture* space. That makes some sense. It's seems weird to call it a "texet-space derivative", because wouldn't "derivative" infer that we're estimating the value, whereas pixels/texels are the smallest possible unit we can measure?

Comment: Haven't heard of texel space before. Yes, pixels are the smallest component/element, and frequently *sampled* as points. Reconstructing the image function with interpolation estimates the in-between values (e.g. bilinear filtering as described in the article) and you can take the derivative of that (again the article describes an issue there). In a practical sense pixels are drawn with area and anti-aliasing techniques give them colour values for the entire area, in which case the colour defines an average value and the pixel is less like a point.